# Why EJB not found when ejb-invoker endpoint used with payara server for EJB remote calls via http

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, payara, java-ee-8

I have prepared simply web services in JavaEE with payara as a web server to check if EJB can be called via http like here: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2021.7/documentation/payara-server/ejb/lite-remote-ejb.html

In the service 1: "ejb_a" created module api:

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloWorld {
    String getHelloWorld();
}
```

and module impl:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(name = "HelloWorld", mappedName = "HelloWorldBean")
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorld() {
        return "Welcome to EJB Tutorial!";
    }
}
```

exposed web service on port 44080

service is archived as war file

and enabled ejb-invocer in payara:
asadmin > set-ejb-invoker-configuration --enabled=true

In the service 2: "ejb_b" created one module

```
import static javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY;
import static javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.ejb.a.HelloWorld;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Singleton
public class RemoteEjbClient {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RemoteEjbClient.class);

    private HelloWorld remoteEjb;

    public RemoteEjbClient() throws NamingException {
        initRemoteServiceViaHttp();
    }

    public HelloWorld getRemoteEjb() {
        return remoteEjb;
    }

    private void initRemoteServiceViaHttp() throws NamingException {
        String host = "localhost";
        String port = "44080";
        Properties environment = new Properties();
        environment.put(INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "fish.payara.ejb.rest.client.RemoteEJBContextFactory");
        environment.put(PROVIDER_URL, String.format("http://%s:%s/ejb-invoker", host, port));

        InitialContext context = new InitialContext(environment);
        remoteEjb = (HelloWorld) context.lookup("java:global/impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld");

        log.info("RemoteEJBMessage: {}", remoteEjb.getHelloWorld());
    }
}
```

and if enable payara with debug and set breakpoint to make evaluate, got exception:
[image]

pom.xml also contains dependency with artifact: ejb-http-client, version 5.2021.7.

Why RemoteEjbClient in service 2 can't lookup EJB HelloWorld in service 1 via http endpoint: localhost:44080/ejb-invoker ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the ejb-invoker is up and running as described in "Configuring HTTP(S) for Remote EJBs" in the [documentation](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/payara-server/ejb/lite-remote-ejb.html)?

If this is the case, please check the path payara\glassfish\domains[your_domain]\endpoints. A folder and a file, indicating deployment or failure of doing so, should be available.

Since this should be an additional service being deployed check if an extra service is running alongside your service at 44080, for reference see the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPRRB.png)